# How to convert stream to bitmap in xamarin.forms to adjust image contrast

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bitmap

I am trying to raise the contrast of an image in Xamarin.forms using [this](https://efundies.com/adjust-the-contrast-of-an-image-in-c/) algorithm. My code gives me in image in the form of a System.IO.Stream, which I want to convert to a Bitmap/LockBitmap to use the algorithm.

I tried code such as `using System.Drawing`, which didn't work. The error said "the type or namespace bitmap could not be found." Then, I tried `using Android.Graphics`, which fixes that error, but I don't know if it will work with a Xamarin.forms app that needs to run on Android and iOS.

Even if that does work, how do I actually convert a System.IO.Stream into a Bitmap? Is there another algorithm that doesn't require bitmaps?

Edit: I think I can use BitmapFactory to convert the stream into a bitmap.

Comment: Use Bitmap.FromStream(stream)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I think the issue is that one is an Android.Graphics.Bitmap and that method might be part of System.Drawing.Bitmap.

Comment: Try DecodeStream.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.bitmapfactory?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: Yep! That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to convert `System.IO.Stream` into `Bitmap` ,after raise the contrast of an image ,return the new stream,and show the `Image` in forms page.

like:

create a interface `IRaiseImage.cs`:

```
public interface IRaiseImage
{
    Stream RaiseImage(Stream stream);
}
```

then in Droid.project,creat `AndroidRaiseImage.cs`:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidRaiseImage))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class AndroidRaiseImage : IRaiseImage
   {
     public Stream RaiseImage(Stream stream)
      {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
        //raise the bitmap contrast
        ...
        // return the new stream
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, ms);
        return ms;
      }
   }
}
```

then you could set to the Image in your forms page:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();//your original image stream
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => DependencyService.Get<IRaiseImage>().RaiseImage(memoryStream));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I solved it earlier using jdweng's comment and bitmapfactory.