# How can I convert an Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource to Android.Graphics.Bitmap?

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, type-conversion

I have an ImageSource from camera view, and I want to convert it to a Bitmap, then to an SKBitmap,
how can I do that?

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)imageData;
```

Comment: You don't.  You would (typically) use the same data source that you used to create the ImageSource and create the bitmap from that.

Comment: Have a look at these threads may help: [converting a Xamarin.Forms ImageSource to the respective Native Images](https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/a-helper-for-converting-a-xamarin-forms-imagesource-to-the-respective-native-images-56a5aaf98156) and [convert stream to bitmap in xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361328/how-to-convert-stream-to-bitmap-in-xamarin-forms-to-adjust-image-contrast).